# Aspnet Core Action request fails but everything works

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action, aspnet-compiler

Why does the request fail even if everything works correctly?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUser(String Cod)
{
   var User = await _context.AwsmAppusers.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Username == Cod);
   if (User == null)
   {
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }

   try
   {
      _context.AwsmAppusers.Remove(User);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      _logger.LogError("Si è verificato un errore nell'eliminazione dell'utente: " + e.Message);                
      return null;/*RedirectToAction("Delete", new { id = id, saveChangesError = true });*/
   }

   return RedirectToAction("UsersPage");
}
```

[Why is the red marker displayed?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrKgh.png)

Comment: Fails? Fails how? The thigh that you are pointing on the picture is a unit test marker - you have a failing unit test. You should add the code for that unit test, otherwise it's hard to tell what is going on.

Comment: You need to give more info on what do you want.

Comment: I do not understand why the red marker appears, even if everything works.

Comment: What do you mean by "the red marker"?

Comment: The white x in the red circle, the one I circled in the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @CriMig8 try to attach your User

```
      _context.AwsmAppusers.Attach(User);
      _context.Remove(User);
      _context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you,but this is just a way of avoiding the protocol "try and catch".

Comment: Yeah you're right. did the   "_context.AwsmAppusers.Attach(User);" worked?

Comment: I updated my Answer.. thanks , by the way the red circle appears when a request to the controller fails.  

Try using [HttpPost] and on your parameter use [FromBody] or [FromQuery] then "string cod" .. sample DeleteUser([FromBody]string Cod)

Comment: [HttpPost] fix it, Thank you!

Comment: Great! Happy to help :-)